# tmux text cut off by split line using iTerm2

Tags: zsh, tmux, iterm2

I am using zsh, iTerm2, and tmux. When I split the window into multiple panes the line covers up a little bit of the text. Here's a picture of what it looks like:

[image]

It works fine using terminal, so I don't think it has anything to do with my tmux configuration.

Comment: what font are you using?

Comment: 18pt Inconsolata

Comment: 18pt? How big is your screen? Then you should try to increase the horizontal spacing in your iterm. The separation line uses the font information itself. So the bigger the font, the bigger the line, loosely speaking

Comment: I am using a 13 inch macbook pro. Making the font smaller made it worse [http://imgur.com/uTTjFYL](http://imgur.com/uTTjFYL). How would I increase the horizontal spacing?

Comment: iterm > Preference > Profiles > Text > Change Font

Comment: Changing the horizontal character spacing and changing the font had little effect. If I move the horizontal character spacing close to maximum distance it no longer is covered up by the line, but the letters are too far away from each other to read comfortably.